# Downloading blob results in more memory being used than size of actual blob

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

Im trying to download a blob thats around 350mb in size. When i used the blob sdk its taking up to 2gb in memory to do. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
        var blobclient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await blobclient.DownloadToAsync(stream);
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var result = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: How did you measure this?

Comment: If the blob is 350 MB, the array is also going to take up 350 MB -- at least, since internally it may have grown larger in response to dynamic alocation. Then *on top of that*, the string you produce with the `StreamReader` is going to take up another 700 MB or so, assuming the blob is mostly ASCII data, since strings are UTF-16 encoded internally. Throw in some eager memory allocation by the runtime and you may well get to the 2 GB mark before you expect it. There may be room for optimization depending on what you're doing with the blob; more streaming is an obvious approach.

Comment: @JeroenMostert when we get the blob which is basically an xml string. We want to convert this into an object for additionally processing.

Comment: That doesn't preclude the use of streaming. You can use `blobClient.DownloadStreaming()` and the `BlobDownloadStreamingResult` to get direct access to a `Stream`. You can then use that stream to create an `XmlReader` which can [selectively read from the blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/linq/stream-xml-fragments-xmlreader) as you build your object representation, or (if you really want to have it all) use `XElement.Load`. Either of these approaches will bypass generating a huge intermediate byte array or string.

Comment: Hi @clonebaby59, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you to please use the **‘StorageTransferOptions’** class in .Net Azure SDK for tuning your performance. `This class has further several values which if defined in the .Net blob storage code can ensure that the transfer size of the blob and the concurrent connections to be initiated for parallel subtransfers to happen`. They are **‘MaximumConcurrency’** and **‘MaximumTransferSize’**.

**‘MaximumConcurrency’ class when used puts restrictions to the .NET’s connection pool limit for asynchronous parallel operations**. Similarly, when **‘MaximumTransferSize’ class is used, it limits the maximum data size of a subtransfer to be supported during download operation**. Thus, `if you use these classes in your .NET Azure SDK code, the memory size consumption in your local system during downloading blobs can be checked` and taken care of.

Please find the below example of the code sample for the usage of the above classes in your .NET Azure SDK code: -

```
  // Path to the directory to upload
string downloadPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\download\\";
Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadPath);
Console.WriteLine($"Created directory {downloadPath}");

// Specify the StorageTransferOptions
var options = new StorageTransferOptions
{
    // Set the maximum number of workers that 
    // may be used in a parallel transfer.
    MaximumConcurrency = 8,

    // Set the maximum length of a transfer to 50MB.
    MaximumTransferSize = 50 * 1024 * 1024
};

List<BlobContainerClient> containers = new List<BlobContainerClient>();

foreach (BlobContainerItem container in blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainers())
{
    containers.Add(blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(container.Name));
}
```

For more information on the above classes and further clarification, kindly refer to the below documentation links: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-scalable-app-download-files?tabs=dotnet#run-the-application***

***https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/tuning-your-uploads-and-downloads-with-the-azure-storage-client-library-for-net/***